# ssh tab auto-complete causes bash: warning: setlocale

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, locale, auto-completion

When I try to to use <kbd>tab</kbd> to auto-complete to finish a ssh (or scp) command, the following error appears on the console:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

This is the result of pressing <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
user@computer:~$ ssh -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

::1             computer            ff02::1         ff02::2         ip6-allnodes    
ip6-allrouters  ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback    localhost
user@computer:~$ ssh _
```

This error message is not displayed when I tab auto complete any other commands, just ssh and scp (as far as I know). I've only started noticing this recently, but I don't believe I've changed anything related to locale. I have several Ubuntu 14.4 machines behaving this way.

Comment: use `set -x` and then try again. It is calling some helper script that is probably trying to set locale to some standard/known one.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje The result of `set -x` was a lot of code, but I couldn't see the culprit in there. However, this has stopped happening on all 3 of the machines I saw it on earlier... so strange...